# requesting to help me by converting pine script version 2 to version 5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, technical-indicator

help me to convert below pine script 3 lines in version 5.(below lines are in version 2)

```
src=ohlc4
haOpen = (src + nz(haOpen[1]))/2
haC=(ohlc4+haOpen+max(high,haOpen)+min(low,haOpen))/4
```

try to convert pine script version 2 to version 5

Answer (score 0):

[Self-referenced variables are removed](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/To_Pine_version_3.html#self-referenced-variables-are-removed)

So, you need to first define the variable and use `:=` to assign a value to it.

```
src=ohlc4
haOpen = 0.0
haOpen := (src + nz(haOpen[1]))/2
haC=(ohlc4+haOpen+math.max(high,haOpen)+math.min(low,haOpen))/4
```